# Sort array by two keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with a couple of names.

```
$array = Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Skyler White
            [fname] => Skyler
            [lname] => White
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Marie Schrader
            [fname] => Marie
            [lname] => Schrader
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Hank Schrader
            [fname] => Hank
            [lname] => Schrader
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Jesse Pinkman
            [fname] => Jesse
            [lname] => Pinkman
        )

)
```

I’d like the array sorted matching the following criteria:

1) last name `lname`
2) first name `fname`

So the ordered array will look like:

```
$array_ordered = Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Jesse Pinkman
            [fname] => Jesse
            [lname] => Pinkman
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Hank Schrader
            [fname] => Hank
            [lname] => Schrader
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Marie Schrader
            [fname] => Marie
            [lname] => Schrader
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Skyler White
            [fname] => Skyler
            [lname] => White
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White
        )

)
```

Comment: Where do you get the data from? This might be easier to do directly when you get it from for example a database.

Comment: From the database I only get the values of the `[fullname]` key. (I split them with the PHP name parser (https://github.com/joshfraser/PHP-Name-Parser).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a callback function to make the comparison, using [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php):

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    $retLastName = strnatcmp($a['lname'], $b['lname']);
    if(!$retLastName) 
         $retLastName = strnatcmp($a['fname'], $b['fname']);
    return $retLastName;
}

usort($array, 'compare');
```

@edit

To explain the use of `strnatcmp`, I will show a little example I think it speaks for itself.

```
function compareStrcmp($a, $b){
   $retLastName = strcmp($a['lname'], $b['lname']);
   if(!$retLastName) 
        $retLastName = strcmp($a['fname'], $b['fname']);
   return $retLastName;
}

function compare($a, $b){
   $retLastName = strnatcmp($a['lname'], $b['lname']);
   if(!$retLastName) 
        $retLastName = strnatcmp($a['fname'], $b['fname']);
   return $retLastName;
}

$arr1 = $arr2 = array(
       0 => array (
            "fullname" => "Walter White",
            "fname" => "Walter",
            "lname" => "White"
       ) , 
       1 => array (
            "fullname" => "Marie Schrader",
            "fname" => "Marie",
            "lname" => "Schrader"
       ) , 
       2 => array (
            "fullname" => "Walter White 1",
            "fname" => "Walter",
            "lname" => "White 1"
       ) ,
       3 => array (
            "fullname" => "Walter White 10",
            "fname" => "Walter",
            "lname" => "White 10"
       ) ,
       4 => array (
            "fullname" => "Walter White 2",
            "fname" => "Walter",
            "lname" => "White 2"
       )
);
echo "Standard string comparison\n";

usort($arr1, 'compareStrcmp');
print_r($arr1);

echo "\nNatural order string comparison\n";
usort($arr2, "compare");
print_r($arr2);
```

Output:

```
Standard string comparison
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Marie Schrader
            [fname] => Marie
            [lname] => Schrader
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White 1
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White 10
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White 2
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White 2
        )

)

Natural order string comparison
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Marie Schrader
            [fname] => Marie
            [lname] => Schrader
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White 1
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White 2
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Walter White 10
            [fname] => Walter
            [lname] => White 10
        )

)
```

As you can see, `strcmp` puts 'Walter White 10' ahead of 'Walter White 2', what probably would be wrong for us humans. `Strnatcmp`, on other hand, does not do that, and displays it correctly.

For more info:

[PHP example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php#refsect1-function.strnatcmp-examples)

[Natsort algorithm](http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/)

Comment: I think you have a tiny little typo in your code in line 5: You spelled `$rretLastName` with two r. With this correction your code works like a charm!

Comment: @1nflktd: do you know anyone called `Walter White 10`?

Comment: @georg c'mon, don't be silly, you know its just an example. But what about if you have dups, would you like to have 10 before 2 ?

Comment: @georg hmm, almost, you missed it by about 14k km away :p